# How to query translated content when using the translate behavior?

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

My website is in multiple languages so an article's title depends on the local. But there's a problem: How can I search for an article in another language?

Right now, the only way is by typing the title in english so that cakePHP retrieves the name in french, for exmple. I can't search for it in french.

For exemple:
When I search for "Hello" I find the article named "Bonjour"
But when I search for "Bonjour" I can't find any article.

So how do I search in another language? It seem that Cakephp search first in default language to then get the traductions.

In my controller:

```
$this->Ingredients->locale('fr_CA');
$data = $this->Ingredients->find('all')
->select([
    'Ingredients.id',
    'Ingredients.name'
])
->where(["Ingredients.name LIKE '%".$this->request->query['k']."%'"])
->order('Ingredients.recipe_count');
```

Comment: Mostly for info, you may find [this behavior](https://github.com/AD7six/cakephp-shadow-translate) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### SQL Injections!

First things first, what you have there is a SQL injection vulnerability, as you are inserting user data into an SQL fragment instead of using the `key => value` format, which would result in proper queries with bound values!

Please be sure to read **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)** for more information on how to properly build advanced conditions!

## Searching translated content

Searching by translated content, well, the Translate behavior adds a `hasOne` association for each translatable field, and by default the naming scheme is `TableAlias_field_translation`, so for example `Ingredients_name_translation`.

The association is being contained automatically, so you can search on its `content` field, which will possibly hold the translated content.

As of CakePHP 3.4.0, respectively 3.4.4, you can use the `translationField()` method provided by the translate behavior, it will return the properly aliased field depending on the locale:

```
->where([
    $this->Ingredients->translationField('name') . ' LIKE' =>
        '%' . $this->request->query('k') . '%'
])
```

Note that before 3.4.4, `translationField()` would not consider the case where the locale set matches the default locale! In that situation you would want to query against the original tables `name` column, but before 3.4.4 the method would always return the `content` column of the associated translation table.

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Translate > Querying Translated Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#querying-translated-fields)**

In versions before CakePHP 3.4, you'll have to build the column name yourself, like:

```
->where([
    'Ingredients_name_translation.content LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query['k'] . '%'
])
```

In the case mentioned above, where the locate set matches the default language, the Translate behavior won't contain the translation table associations, so you'd have to take appropriate measures to ensure that the correct field is being used in the conditions, based on the language in use, ie use `Ingredients.name` in case the default language is being used!

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you I just needed the scheme for the request. As for the SQL injection, I just changed the code a bit too fast to make it more readable for you guys :P No SQL Injections in my code. Thank you!